# Суммировать значение несколько таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Есть четыре таблицы, у каждого из них есть поля, под названием `price` (значение которого нужно суммировать). Делаю отчет, нужно суммировать поля этих четырёх таблиц.

Нужно сумма всех полей `price`. Как мне это выполнять?

Comment: `union all` и суммировать

Comment: либо сумма подзапросов суммирования

Comment: А если таблицы MyISAM, можно построить MERGE-надтаблицу.

Comment: @Akina нравится мне, когда новичку советуют то, что не всякий продвинутый сделает. Zolushka, как соединяете таблицы?

Comment: @TotalPusher То, что он новичок, ещё не означает, что он идиот. А что такое MyISAM Engine, и как использовать MERGE Engine, вполне вменяемо расписано в документации.

Comment: Что вы уже сделали? Как пробовали решить свою задачу? С какими проблемами столкнулись?

Comment: Спасибо вам все за отзывы. Я использовала отдельные запросы.

Comment: Извините! Дайте еще совет на тему... Вообщем лучше писать хран.процедуры, функции и триггеры на среди базы или лучше всего этого писать на стороне PHP???

Comment: Извините еще раз если перегнула палку. Просто сейчас мне нужно создать, не знаю с чего начать? Поэтому дорогие учителя-виртуали, помогите мне со советом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как самый простой способ, так сказать в лоб, это использовать [UNION ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) и одним запросом с подзапросом получить одну цифру:

```
SELECT SUM(`sum`) AS `total` FROM (
    (SELECT SUM(`price`) AS `sum` FROM `table_first`) UNION ALL
    (SELECT SUM(`price`) AS `sum` FROM `table_second`) UNION ALL
    (SELECT SUM(`price`) AS `sum` FROM `table_third`) UNION ALL
    (SELECT SUM(`price`) AS `sum` FROM `table_last`)
) AS `all_tables`;
```

Не знаю сколько у вас записей и как быстро этот запрос будет летать, возможно лучше будет выполнить 4 отдельных простых запроса к каждой таблице и потом суммировать на PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто. Вот самый простой запрос:

```
SELECT
    SUM(table1.price) AS sumPrice1,
    SUM(table2.price) AS sumPrice2,
    SUM(table3.price) AS sumPrice3,
    SUM(table4.price) AS sumPrice4
FROM
    table1, table2, table3, table4
LIMIT 1
```

Потом PHP получаем суммы столбцов каждой таблицы и складываем:

```
$resSum = $row['sumPrice1'] + $row['sumPrice2'] + $row['sumPrice3'] + $row['sumPrice4'];
echo $resSum; // сумма всех столбцов 4-х таблиц
```

Comment: а зачем тут лимит?